# How to package and distribute a Keyboard Layout

Tags: macos, keyboard, ukelele

I'm using [Ukele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create a new keyboard for my language.

I can't find information regarding how to distribute it so that users can easily install and use it.

Comment: Check the Ukelele manual regarding .bundle format and Ask on the group devoted to Ukelele:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyboard layouts can be installed in one of the following locations: /Library/Keyboard Layouts/ ~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/ /Network/Library/Keyboard Layouts/

Also, perhaps useful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2056/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003085

hope that helps

Comment: How does this relate to Ukele (the application the OP is using)?

Comment: you could just provide a readme saying place "mylayout.keylayout" in /Library/Keyboard Layouts/

or you could try making an Installer Plug-in

Comment: Well it sort of helped me, but not an answer and not a -1 at all @patrix as 
I found this helpful:

"Keyboard layouts can be installed in one of the following locations:

`/Library/Keyboard Layouts/  ~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/  /Network/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`"

Comment: Good to hear it helped you, but wouldn't the part you've wrote in the comment be more useful than a link to some overall documentation which may or may not contain the answer?

Comment: It's from the same link @kipbits answered